# Rational arithmetic from given input

Tags: c++, rational-numbers

I'm currently working on [this](https://open.kattis.com/problems/rationalarithmetic) for my own practice. I get 4 digits and an operation.

The input is `x1 y1 op x2 y2` and the fraction is `x1/y1` and `x2/y2`. If I get the input: `1 3 + 1 2` then it's `1/3 + 1/2` and the answer should be given the minimal fractional so it's `5/6`. I pass the testcases I get and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

To summarize what I do:

1. Read input and check the operation if it's `+`,`-`,`/` or `*`. I generate a prime array to find the biggest common divisor.
2. Send the input to a function depending on which operation it is.
3. I count the given input with simple math.
4. Then I find the biggest common divisor and divide both numerator and denominator with this.
5. After that I print out the result.

Here is the main function and how I handle if the operation is `*`. I handle the other operation the same but with other math.

```
    #include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <iterator>
#include <array>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstddef>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <math.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <algorithm>

       using namespace std;

long long  nwd(long long a, long long b){
    long long  c;
    while(b != 0){
        c = a % b;
        a = b;
        b = c;
    }
    return a;
}

void add(long long x1, long long y1, long long x2, long long y2){
    long long bottom = (y1) * (y2);
    long long top = ((x1) * (y2)) + ((x2) * (y1));
    //cout << bottom << " " << top << endl;
    long long frac;
    if(bottom != 0||top != 0){
        frac = nwd(top,bottom);
    }else{
        frac = 1;
    }
    string sign = "";
    if(top * bottom < 0){
        sign = "-";
    }else{
        sign = "";
    }
    printf("%s%lld / %lld\n",sign.c_str(),abs(top/frac),abs(bottom/frac) );
}

void sub(long long x1, long long y1,long long x2, long long y2){
    long long bottom = (y1) * (y2);
    long long top = ((x1) * (y2)) - ((x2) * (y1));
    long long frac;
    if(bottom != 0||top != 0){
        frac = nwd(top,bottom);
    }else{
        frac = 1;
    }
    string sign = "";
    if(top * bottom < 0){
        sign = "-";
    }else{
        sign = "";
    }
    printf("%s%lld / %lld\n",sign.c_str(),abs(top/frac),abs(bottom/frac) );
}

void divi(long long x1, long long y1, long long x2, long long y2){
    long long top = (x1) * (y2);
    long long bottom = (x2) * (y1);
    long long frac;
    if(bottom != 0||top != 0){
        frac = nwd(top,bottom);
    }else{
        frac = 1;
    }
    string sign = "";
    if(top * bottom < 0){
        sign = "-";
    }else{
        sign = "";
    }
    printf("%s%lld / %lld\n",sign.c_str(),abs(top/frac),abs(bottom/frac) );
}

void mult(long long x1, long long y1, long long x2, long long y2){
    long long top = (x1) * (x2);
    long long bottom = (y2) * (y1);
    long long frac;
    if(bottom != 0||top != 0){
        frac = nwd(top,bottom);
    }else{
        frac = 1;
    }
    string sign = "";
    if(top * bottom < 0){
        sign = "-";
    }else{
        sign = "";
    }
    printf("%s%lld / %lld\n",sign.c_str(),abs(top/frac),abs(bottom/frac) );
}

int main()
{

    int numOp;
    scanf("%d", &numOp);
    while(numOp != 0){
        long long x1,x2,y1,y2;
        char op[2];
        scanf("%lld %lld %s %lld %lld", &x1, &y1, op, &x2, &y2);
        if( op[0] == '+'){
            add(x1, y1, x2,y2);
        }
        else if(op[0] == '-'){
            sub(x1,y1,x2,y2);
        }
        else if(op[0] == '/'){
            divi(x1,y1,x2,y2);
        }
        else{
            mult(x1,y1,x2,y2);
        }
        numOp--;
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

[Here](http://ideone.com/jBddSI) is my code with the given testcase and I get the correct result. I need some tips with either different testcases or any suggestions.

Comment: Use of name `nwd` for what is called in English GCD (Greatest Common Divisor) suggests you might be from Poland. ;) It is better to use English names for readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a number of things that may help you improve your code.

### Use only required `#include`s

The code has a great number of `#include`s that are not needed.  Some files are even listed twice.  This clutters the code and makes it more difficult to read and understand.  Only include files that are actually needed.

### Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY)

The mathematical operations all include large portions of repeated code.  Instead of repeating code, it's generally better to make common code into a function.

### Don't abuse `using namespace std`

Putting `using namespace std` at the top of every program is [a bad habit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) that you'd do well to avoid.

### Use objects

Since you're writing in C++, what would make more sense to me would be to create a rational fraction object. Then each mathematical operation would be very naturally expressed as an operator on the object.

### Use `switch` instead of nested `if`

The more appropriate control flow for your `if` statement in `main` is a `switch` statement.  This makes it somewhat clearer to read and understand and often provides a small improvement in performance, especially if there are many cases.

### Prefer `iostream` to `stdio.h`

Using `iostream` style I/O makes the code easier to adapt to change.  For example, using `scanf`, the code has to have the appropriate matching format string for each argument, but using the `>>` operator, there is no such requirement and the compiler adapts automatically to whatever type is being read.

### Omit `return 0`

When a C++ program reaches the end of `main` the compiler will automatically generate code to return 0, so there is no reason to put `return 0;` explicitly at the end of `main`.

### Putting it all together

Here's an alternative implementation which uses all of these suggestions.  Note that a rational fraction is only reduced when it is being printed.  This saves some time over always maintaining that state.

```
#include <iostream>

class RationalFraction
{
public:
    RationalFraction(long long a=0, long long b=1)
        : num{a}, den{b}
        { }
    // unary negation
    RationalFraction& operator-() { num = -num; return *this; }
    // add the passed fraction to this one
    // The two-operand addition is built from this, and a 
    // similar pattern is used for each of the other operators.
    RationalFraction& operator+=(const RationalFraction &rh) {
        num = num * rh.den + rh.num *den;
        den *= rh.den;
        return *this;
    }
    RationalFraction& operator-=(const RationalFraction &rh) {
        num = num * rh.den - rh.num *den;
        den *= rh.den;
        return *this;
    }
    RationalFraction& operator*=(const RationalFraction &rh) {
        num *= rh.num;
        den *= rh.den;
        return *this;
    }
    RationalFraction& operator/=(const RationalFraction &rh) {
        num *= rh.den;
        den *= rh.num;
        return *this;
    }
    friend std::ostream &operator<< (std::ostream& out, const RationalFraction& f) {
        RationalFraction fr=f;
        fr.reduce();
        return out << fr.num << " / " << fr.den;
    }
    friend std::istream &operator>> (std::istream& in, RationalFraction& f) {
        return in >> f.num >> f.den;
    }

private:
    void reduce() {
        if (num == 0) {
            den = 1;
            return;
        }
        long long mygcd = gcd(num, den);
        num /= mygcd;
        den /= mygcd;
        if (den < 0) {
            den = -den;
            num = -num;
        }
    }
    long long gcd(long long a, long long b) const {
        long long  c;
        while(b != 0){
            c = a % b;
            a = b;
            b = c;
        }
        return a;
    }

    // data members
    long long num, den;
};

RationalFraction operator+(RationalFraction lh, const RationalFraction &rh)
{
    lh += rh;
    return lh;
}

RationalFraction operator-(RationalFraction lh, const RationalFraction &rh)
{
    lh -= rh;
    return lh;
}

RationalFraction operator*(RationalFraction lh, const RationalFraction &rh)
{
    lh *= rh;
    return lh;
}

RationalFraction operator/(RationalFraction lh, const RationalFraction &rh)
{
    lh /= rh;
    return lh;
}

int main()
{
    int numOp;
    for (std::cin >> numOp; numOp; --numOp) {
        RationalFraction lhs, rhs;
        char op[2];
        std::cin >> lhs >> op >> rhs;
        switch (op[0]) {
            case '+':
                std::cout << lhs+rhs << '\n';
                break;
            case '-':
                std::cout << lhs-rhs << '\n';
                break;
            case '/':
                std::cout << lhs/rhs << '\n';
                break;
            default:
                std::cout << lhs*rhs << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

#### A bit more detail

To understand this version of the code, it's useful to look at a few individual class member functions.  First, is the constructor:

```
    RationalFraction(long long a=0, long long b=1)
        : num{a}, den{b}
        { }
```

This allows for construction in a few different ways:

```
RationalFraction half{1,2};   // 1/2 = one half
RationalFraction three{3};    // 3/1 = 3
RationalFraction zero;        // 0/1 = 0
```

The basic four mathematical functions are all built in the same way.  First, there is a member function such as `+=`:

```
    RationalFraction& operator+=(const RationalFraction &rh) {
        num = num * rh.den + rh.num *den;
        den *= rh.den;
        return *this;
    }
```

This version is a member function and can be used like this:

```
RationalFraction a{1,3};
RationalFraction b{1,2};  
a += b;    // now a = 5/6 and b is unchanged
```

It's a common idiom to define those member functions first and then construct the two-operand versions:

```
RationalFraction operator+(RationalFraction lh, const RationalFraction &rh)
{
    lh += rh;
    return lh;
}
```

This is a bit subtle.  Note that `lh` is passed by value, so that means a local copy is constructed using the compiler-generated default copy.  By contrast `rh` is a `const` reference, so no additional copy is created.  Now all we need to do is apply the member function version and return `lh` which, remember, is a copy of whatever was originally passed in for that parameter.  It is a standalone function and not a member function so that either of these works:

```
RationalFraction f={-1,2};
std::cout << f+3 << std::endl;  // (-1/2) + 3 = 5/2
std::cout << 3+f << std::endl;  // 3 + (-1/2) = 5/2
```

In the expression `3+f` first a temporary rational fraction is created from `3`.  Then that rational fraction is added to `f` and the result displayed using the `<<` operator.  That is, it's approximately the equivalent to this:

```
RationalFraction temp1{3};   // = 3/1
RationalFraction temp2 = temp1 + f;  // do addition using non-member function
std::cout << temp2 << std::endl;  // show the result = 5/2
```

The only other slightly tricky bit of code is in private member function `reduce`.  Here I've added comments to make it easier to understand:

```
void reduce() {
    // if it's of the form 0/x, turn it into canonical 0/1
    if (num == 0) {
        den = 1;
        return;
    }
    // reduce by dividing by the greatest common divisor of 
    // numerator and denominator
    long long mygcd = gcd(num, den);
    num /= mygcd;
    den /= mygcd;
    // Only allow the numerator to be negative to simplify printing.
    // Changing sign of both numerator and denominator has no
    // mathematical effect on the value.
    if (den < 0) {
        den = -den;
        num = -num;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the support! Im a beginner at c++ so not really sure how to construct the code yet! Thanks for all the tips.

Comment: If you have time can you explain what the different functions in the class does it seem a bit hard for me to understand! Thanks in advance

Comment: I've added additional explanation to my answer.

Comment: Thanks helps me alot! Its very nice and clean code do you have any booktips or anything else to pratice this?

Comment: Yes, I highly recommend *The C++ Programming Language, 4th ed.* by Bjarne Stroustrup.

Comment: I will definitely look in to that one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, do you really want to use `long long` everywhere ? Some simple `int` aren't enough ? It will really ease the reading to do so.

You really should factorize the `+` and `-` operators. You will save tons of line of code and bugs. As you know, `x1 y1 sub x2 y2` is equivalent to `x1 y1 add -x2 y2`. Same for `*` and `/` : `x1 y1 div x2 y2` is equivalent to `x1 y1 mul y2 x2`

You never test whether your rationals are valid or not. the bottom of each fractions shall always be non-null, but you never test it.
You should add this kind of test case : give invalid values to the main, and see if it crashes, do something wrong, or return an error/exception (that you need to implement).

Have you done tests case where you give non-reduced rationals to your function (like 6/2 + 12/3) ? It should work, and you should test it.

One or two more remarks :

- Prefer the C++ printing (with `std::cout`) over the C-style printing. You're writing C++, not C (plus, it's clearer and easier to read).
- Don't hesitate to give more explicit names (I don't know what "nwd" stands for...), auto-completion compensate verbosity.
- I always prefer `main()` parameters over `scanf`, which is less reliable (and require cautious over flushes). Just read `argv` ! Moreover, you will probably save lines of code.
- Are all these libs really required ? Anyway, prefer C++ libs over C-converted libs. As I said, you write C++, not C.

That's all I can see for now.